# How can I implement this interaction model with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, binding

With jQuery, I'm interested in creating the following interaction model.

1. When a user types in the page, anytime jQuery notices three !, "!!!" typed in a row, to be able to do something about it.
2. After noticing three !, "!!!", wrap the previous sentence (finding the last period from the location the user is currently typing and wrapping a `<span class=Important>`

How can I do this?

Comment: Is the user typing into an `<input/>`, a `<textarea>`, or something else?

Comment: The user is typing in a TEXTAREA

Comment: Once the text has been wrapped, do you want the `!!!` to be removed from the textarea, or kept there?

Answer (score 6):

This should work.  I've set it up as a live event handler (so that it works for elements dynamically added to the page), but you could use the exact same function as a normal keyup handler on any `textarea` or `input` element as well.

It checks to see whether the element's current value ends with `!!!` and if so performs the replacement, both using simple regular expressions.

```
$("input,textarea").live("keyup", function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var value = $this.val();

    if (/!!!$/.test(value)) {
        $this.val(value.replace(/(\.?)([^.]+?\.?\s*)!!!$/, '$1<span class="important">$2</span>'));
    }
});
```

Comment: Great answer. I was about to post something similar.

Comment: Very cool idea! It doesn't seem to be working just yet thought, something wrong in the IF

Comment: Also, will this grab just the most recent sentence based on the period?

Comment: Looks like it's the $this.val(value.replace which is breaking

Comment: That code was requiring a period to be in front, which won't work for the first sentence. I made it optional.

http://jsbin.com/abira3/3/edit

Comment: @Patrick — Good catch!  I only tested it with two sentences; I'll update my answer.

Comment: Very cool! I'm curious, would this approach work for modern editors that use iframes like: <body contenteditable="true"> ? or is it required to have an INPUT for the val() line?

Comment: @WozPoz — I haven't tried it with `contenteditable`, but as long as `keyup` events are fired (and I'm pretty sure they are), it should work just fine.

Comment: @Ben. That's great. I tried it out of curiosity and I doesn't strangely enough. The only difference should be using .html() instead of .val()

Comment: @Ben, if you remove the "contenteditable="true"" in the body tag it works otherwise it doesn't. Horribly strange

Comment: @Ben, I believe the reason contenteditable isn't working is bec: #1, Val() needs to be html(). Also, when the text isn't in a textarea, the browser adds HTML tags, so what was helloben!!! is now ...helloben!!!</p>, is there a way to update the regext to support this? If you'd prefer I open a new question, please let me know - thxs!

Comment: @WozPoz — I've played around with it a bit and there's no simple way to do it.  (Regexes don't work well with nested structures like raw HTML.)  I think you could get it working using the browser's text selection capabilities, but it would be a great deal more complicated.

Answer (score 0):

As much as I am loathe to say that jQuery isn't good for something - perhaps this kind of logic is better handled on the server.  Unless they are typing in an HTML editor where the newly inserted span tags are invisible to the user, it may be a little disconcerting to be typing in a textarea/textbox and suddenly see a bunch of HTML inserted into my comment.